# Senior member steals edit

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I recently suggested an edit to a question with a tag that I thought would be good for the question, this morning when I check to see if my edit got accepted I see that the tag is there but the question has been edited by another member that can edit without being verified, why didn't he accept my edit? Seems to me like he just stole my edit.

Comment: Besides it's not *steal* but another *revision*, if your edit is mostly okay, it's likely to keep and count. If it's wrong, then it's a *reject*.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You [were adding the wrong tags](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22116394) to that question.

The other user corrected your edit and [added the appropriate tags](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/54522774/2).

The question was not about Amazon Web Services, but about Azure.

Comment: Oh now i see, I was adding aws tags instead of azure

Comment: Try to be more careful, both in your edits and your accusations.

Comment: @Cody, don't do [that](https://cl.ly/a91ce2). I was trying to have a nice cup of tea. And nice to have you back on meta. Hadn't seen you in quite a while.

Comment: Sorry about your tea. Hope I didn't ruin your keyboard. But I'm afraid I can't stop. Also, very nice to be back. Cheers!

Comment: @yivi yes, but this question is also about what to do in case someone really steals your edit.

Comment: @yihi what should I do in case someone steals my edit.

Comment: What edit do you refer to, @DipanshuMahla? "Stealing" edits is not really a thing. The only users who can approve/reject/improve a suggested edits are users who no longer gain reputation from edits in any case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70520870/javascript-object-as-parameter I have made simple edits to this question and as I was answering the question it had an edit from a mod with more than 4000 reputation.

Comment: That user is not a moderator, it's a regular user with more reputation. Again, they cannot "steal" the edit, since they gain nothing. If I compare [their edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70520870/revisions) and [your edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30697902), I'm sure I'll see the other edit fixed some things you neglected to fix. Check the differences, so you can know how to better suggest edits in the future.

Comment: @yivi thanks for clarification